# How to fix encoding in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

When I make a dump of my db (Postgresql 16.0) I get an encoding error symbols. See the attached file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqy0S.png)
I don't know how to fix it. Also, the symbols appear when I try to restore the db. However, the dump itself is good, when I open in with Notepad, I see no problem at all.
UTF-8 is set in Preferences->general->workspace. But the problem still exists.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mLtD.png)

Comment: First, ensure that your PostgreSQL database is using the correct character encoding. `SELECT datname, pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) AS encoding FROM pg_database;`